# How do I dynamically change jqplot pie chart color of a single slice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, jqplot

I want to change the color of a single slice of my piechart whenever I click on it(like being highlighted), thus giving it the impression of being actively selected.

I know it has to be placed somewhere inside my

$(selector).bind('jqplotDataClick', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {...}

You guys have any idea how to do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$(selector).bind('jqplotDataClick', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
   plot.series[seriesIndex].seriesColors[pointIndex]="#FFF"; // FFF is white, you could add any color here to change it
   plot.replot();
});
```

where "plot" is the variable holding the plot.

Comment: hi, I've used plot.replot(); but it has an overhead/delay for sometimes. This would become an issue for our trigger happy client, is there another way to dynamically update the slice rather than replot? or is there a workaround for this? thanks.

Comment: If the color changes dynamically the chart has to drawn again...instead of replot() you could try and you redraw() maybe it's faster.